# Creating a horizontal bar chart extension on Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am using [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) - obviously for creating charts.

I want to have a horizontal bar chart in my app, but it seems that [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) does not have it, therefore I resorted to a fork of that repo called [ChartNew.js.](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js)

ChartNew.js however is not at all responsive, and the thing that attracted me the most to [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) is the ability to have responsive charts.

I am aware that [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) allows [easy extension](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-chart-types) or 'hacking' of the existing chart objects.

> Is it possible to '[extend' Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-extending-existing-chart-types) regular bar chart into
>   becoming a horizontal bar chart?

Comment: Would you prefer other charting libraries aside from Chart.js?

Comment: That would be a last resort option. I much prefer to have uniform aesthetics between the charts, using one library for the size savings, code readability and.. well, simplicity. If it is possible to just extend Chart.js, that would be the ideal

Comment: For the horizontal charts and using alternative software what did you have in mind? I have the same problem and don't want to extend ChartJS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chart.js does not come with horizontal bar charts by default.

However it is built in a very modular fashion. This allows third party plugins to be developed that do not mess with the core code.

As I needed horizontal bar charts for a project I was working on I took the liberty of creating one which you can find here.

https://github.com/tomsouthall/Chart.HorizontalBar.js

You can install it using bower:

```
$ bower install chart.horizontalbar
```

The syntax for creating a chart is exactly the same as for creating a standard (vertical) bar chart:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).HorizontalBar(data, options);
```

It's a pretty quickly hacked together project but it worked great for what I needed! Hope it helps.

Comment: Sir is there any way we can set width of bars?

Comment: This is working quite well, yet the animation is a little odd when using stacked bars. Each bar animates synchronously with each other. Is there any way to make the later bars draw after the left most bars have already drawn, as if it is one bar that is animating. I've been trying to solve this but my eyes are starting to cross starring at it.

Answer (score 5):

I know it might be not helpful to you but might help someone else, google charts are really good take a look at it https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: it's really great and easy to use best part is it's fully customizable  to suit our needs